# How does this printf code work without using va_args?

Tags: c, variadic-functions

The code in question is from [grub](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/multiboot/multiboot.html#kernel_002ec). Normally in a printf implementation, you'd see `stdarg` and `va_start`, `va_list`, `va_end` and `va_arg`, but they seem to be doing some casting here. My guess is that they're relying on some strange trick to grab the parameters and `(int *)` is similar to `va_arg(parameter, int)`. Is this portable code? How does it work?

```
/* Format a string and print it on the screen, just like the libc
   function printf. */
void
printf(const char *format, ...) {
    char **arg = (char **) &format;
    int c;
    char buf[20];

    arg++;

    while ((c = *format++) != 0) {
        if (c != '%')
            putchar(c);
        else {
            char *p;

            c = *format++;
            switch (c) {
                case 'd':
                case 'u':
                case 'x':
                    itoa(buf, c, *((int *) arg++));
                    p = buf;
                    goto string;
                    break;

                case 's':
                    p = *arg++;
                    if (!p)
                        strcpy(p, "(null)");

string:
                    while (*p)
                        putchar(*p++);
                    break;

                default:
                    putchar(*((int *) arg++));
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Is this portable code?" — No.

Answer (score 2):

This is *not* portable code. It assumes that `va_list` is essentially just an array of arguments, and makes a number of dangerous assumptions about the calling convention in use.

It can only work for calling conventions where every single argument is passed on the stack, and even then it isn't guaranteed to work: for example, padding may be used to align extra-wide arguments. Further, it isn't guaranteed that `&format` even obtains the start address of the argument list on the stack (`&format` may well be a local temporary variable by the time the function starts).

For calling conventions that pass some arguments in registers (ARM EABI, x86 __fastcall, x86_64, and several other ABIs), this breaks completely.

Comment: Even if all arguments are on the stack, there is no reason to believe `&format` is the address of the stack slot used to *pass the value* that `format` initially holds. `format` could very well live at a completely different location.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not portable code, and it does not remotely work on any modern compiler. It assumes the arguments to the function arrive in an array of type `char *[N]` whose beginning overlaps with the local variable `format`. This is of course false, but matched the way *some compilers* might have chosen to position `format` on *some ABIs* (mainly, just i386) in the past.

Answer (score 0):

This code makes certain assumptions about the order in which arguments are passed to the function.

In particular, it assumes that the addresses of the arguments are contiguous.

It is not portable because it will break as soon as this assumption is violated.